# How to change the colorbar range in plotly express graph?

Tags: plotly

How can I change the color range in ploty express scatter plots?

```
import plotly.express as px

...

fig = px.scatter(data, 
                 x="X-coord", 
                 y="Y-coord", 
                 animation_frame="Timepoint",
                 color="Fraction", 
                 hover_name="Compound",
                 size_max=10,
                 size='Fraction')
```

[image]

I want the colorbars to show a range from 0 to 1.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can add `range_color=(0,1)` to the keywords of `px.scatter`.

Comment: Works also for px.density_heatmap and probably all other colorbars.

Comment: sometimes we can use `zmin, zmax` parameters

Comment: How can I do this for `plotly.graph_objects.Heatmap`?

Comment: @smoquet Heatmap uses `zmin`, `zmax`.